# Remap <C-n> and <C-p> for popup menu in vim

Tags: vim

There are two ways to select candidate in popup-menu.

1 `<C-n> or <C-p>` can select candidate and auto fill keyword.

[image]

2 `<Up> or <Down>` to select candidate need to press enter to finish the completion.

You can also read this link about up and down in popupmenu-keys.([this](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#popupmenu-keys))

[image]

I prefer to the behavior of `<Up> or <Down>`, but I don't like to press arrows in vim.

I decide to remap `<C-n> or <C-p>`, and let `<C-n> or <C-p>` to do the same behavior.

This is my config.

`imap <expr><C-n> pumvisible() ? "\<Down>" : "    \<C-n>"`

`imap <expr><C-p> pumvisible() ? "\<Up>" : "    \<C-p>"`

---

I change my config with the answer.

There are two cases that I meet.

1.To trigger the popup menu with `<c-n>`, and it works well.

2.To trigger the popup menu with `<c-x><c-p>`, and it doesn't. `<C-n> or <C-p>` works by default.

Comment: You mapped up and down, maybe that's why left and right don't work.

Comment: Sorry I type wrong word. Left and Right can't select candidate.

Comment: Huh? With the popup menu visible, you can already choose among candidates with Up and Down, and Return selects and inserts it.

Comment: Yeah, you want the default behavior so… don't do anything.

Comment: There is a difference between `<c-p> <c-n>` and `up down`. `up down` need press enter to finish completion.

Comment: I don't like to press arrows in vim. So I decide to remap `c-n c-p`

Answer (score 2):

Your whole question is hard to understand (even after all those edits; you don't explain your attempt well), but the following two things are definitely odd:

```
:imap <expr><C-n> pumvisible() ? "\<Down>" : " \<C-n>"
```

1. With that space character in front of `<C-n>`, you won't be able to trigger completion on an existing base. It'll always insert a space, and then offer *all* completion candidates!
2. With `:imap` (and because of the space character), this becomes a *recursive mapping*, so it will just busy-wait. Use `:inoremap`.

That makes it:

```
:inoremap <expr><C-n> pumvisible() ? "\<Down>" : "\<C-n>"
```

which works well for me (but I don't know whether that is what you actually want).